# A single word for describing someone who's both great at writing and speaking

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Writing and speaking are relevant to each other; they both employ words in expressing ideas. Wondering if there's an adjective for describing someone who's impressive in writing and speaking.

The closest I could think of is ***articulate***, but most dictionaries I checked don't mention writing when defining the adjective.

Comment: Another close possibility could be ***lyrical*** in the context of being able to convey emotion in a beautiful way through speech, song, or written literature.

Comment: And some of such genre, are in other respects not much use to mankind. I am wondering what we call them.

Comment: They are different skills, writing and speaking. Some people lack confidence in speaking yet excel in writing. And some are very articulate speakers who struggle to compose on paper. Different skills, different words, I think.

Comment: Are you asking for a word that is applicable to either—or a word that means you are necessarily good at *both*? (Is your question about being good at writing and/or speaking—or about being good at writing **and** speaking?)

Comment: *Articulate* works just fine for written expression.  See, for example, expressing oneself readily, clearly, and effectively -- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/articulate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider ***eloquent***:

> **1** Fluent or persuasive in speaking or writing.
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eloquent)</sub>